# Nomenclature: type relationships in OOP

Tags: oop, class-hierarchy, nomenclature

I'm familiar with the practical aspects of OOP. Now I'm writing a technical document and I'm questioning my use of terms.

[image]

Take this class hierarchy. Each class has zero, one, or more (multiple inheritance) classes it directly derives from. For B, this is A. I'd say that A is B's *base class* or *superclass* (interchangeably).

Conversely, a class can have any number of classes directly deriving from it. I'd say that B and C are A's *derived classes* or *subclasses*, again interchangeably.

Yet there must also be a term to refer to all classes a class *directly or indirectly* inherits from. How would you call {A, B} from D's perspective?

And I'm missing another term for all classes *directly or indirectly* derived from a class. How would you call {B, C, D, E} from A's perspective?

Comment: You're overthinking it. _Derived_ , _child_ , _subclass_ are all valid terms which tell you the fact the class B/C/D/E inherits A. Direct or indirect descendent, it shouldn't matter in practice because of the Liskov Substitution Principle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good questions. In this case, A is the *root class*, as all other classes inherit from it. All objects *descend* from A, or are either direct or indirect subclasses of A. The opposite is also true. B is a direct superclass of D and A is an indirect superclass. I suppose you could use the word *ancestor* as the opposite of descend/descendant, but I haven't seen this before.

Comment: This would mean that the term "subclass"/"superclass" in itself is ambiguous. To be specific, one would have to say "direct" vs. "indirect" subclass/superclass. Makes sense to me.